# git subtree fetch - unwanted remote tags

Tags: git, git-subtree

I am getting started with git subtree.

When fetching from a subtree remote, one thing I notice is that after a git fetch, I have all the tags from this remote. These tags could be something like `v1.0.5`, and it is impossible to distinguish tags from different remotes.

This behavior is technically not surprising. But it is still undesirable.

One solution could be to omit the tags with `git fetch -n`.

I wonder if this is the recommended way to do things, or if there is something smarter that people do. The `-n` option is not mentioned in the tutorials I read so far.

---

Note: I am using git subtree as described [here](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec#.nqmwebixd), the "manual" approach.

Note: An answer that simply confirms the `git fetch -n` can be perfectly valid and acceptable - ideally with a link or two.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following 3 lines to work with subtree

```
git remote add <alias> <url>
git config --local --add remote.<alias>.fetch +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/<alias>/*
git config remote.<alias>.tagopt --no-tags
```

Everytime you call `git fetch <alias>` the tag information of that remote is stored in a subfolder. 
The command `git ls-remote --tags <alias>` eventually lists these tags.